# complus Exception code -532462766

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, exception, c#-4.0

Using visual studio 2010, entity framework 4.0, ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator

On the code lines:

> MecDbEnt.Domains.AddObject(subject);
>
> MecDbEnt.SaveChanges();   (on this line)

the application throws follow exception:

> complus exception code -532462766

Does anyone know how to solve an error like this?

Thx!

Answer (score 20):

I know that -532462766 is the default "general" error code, when a .NET console program terminates with an unhandled exception.

Does the SaveChanges() do a subcall to any console program?