# Load TFS WorkItemDocument

Tags: c#

Doing some tfs automation and have been retrieving WorkItemDocument objects with the GetWorkItem call however on a workitem that is retrieved I get the error in the title. Where can I find the description for the error or why its generating the error?

_COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766

I have googled around and no definitions for this exception.

```
foreach (int i in (doc2 as IResultsDocument).SelectedItemIds)
{
    _lockToken1 = new object();
    IWorkItemDocument widoc = docsrv2.GetWorkItem(tfscoll, i, _lockToken1);
    if (widoc == null) continue;

    Debug.Print("Project name: {0}", widoc.Item.Project.Name);
    if (!widoc.IsLoaded) // Does not load and errors
    {
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312758/736079

Comment: Thanks. Still digging deeper as a general exception still wont point me in the right direction. I have permissions to the workitem/projects so the other thing to look into is the locks as its failing when loading the second workitem

Comment: I see not `using` statements or calls to `.Close()` or `.Dispose()`, in case of COM exceptions always a common option...

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now Thanks! It was a resource lock on the object within the loop not allowing the second or more items to load. Upon each iteration I now properly release and dispose of the lock and also in any exit iteration scenarios. Needed a dastardly DoEvents but its working great now.

```
//...
//...
foreach (int i in (doc2 as IResultsDocument).SelectedItemIds)
{
    _lockToken1 = new object();
    IWorkItemDocument widoc = docsrv2.GetWorkItem(tfscoll, i, _lockToken1);
    if (widoc == null) continue;

    if (!widoc.IsLoaded)
    {
        widoc.Load();
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        while (!widoc.IsLoaded && DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds <= 2.0)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        //...
        //...
        //...
    }
    widoc.Item.Close();
    widoc.Release(_lockToken1);
    //...
//...
```